# How to use binding in WPF with Caliburn.Micro and with UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, caliburn.micro

I have created a UserControl with some fields. I would like to use it and bind data to these fields. Most of them are static values but the `DataValue` property comes from one property of the MainView.
My code:

DataDisplayer.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="TabletMachineAccess.Controls.DataDisplayer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabletMachineAccess.Controls"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             x:Name="dataDisplayer"
             MaxHeight="100"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Border Height="auto"
            Margin="5"
            Padding="5,2,5,2"
            BorderBrush="Gray"
            BorderThickness="2"
            CornerRadius="5">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataType}" />
                <TextBlock Text=":" />
            </StackPanel>
            <Separator Style="{StaticResource BasicSeparator}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Text="{Binding Path=DataValue,
                                      ElementName=dataDisplayer}" />
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock FontWeight="ExtraLight" Text="(" />
                <TextBlock FontWeight="ExtraLight" Text="{Binding UnitText}" />
                <TextBlock FontWeight="ExtraLight" Text=")" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

DataDisplayer.xaml.cs

```
public partial class DataDisplayer : UserControl
{
    public double DataValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(DataValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DataValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DataValue", typeof(double), typeof(DataDisplayer), new PropertyMetadata(9.9));

    public string DataType
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string UnitText
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public DataDisplayer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

I try to use it like this in MainView.xaml

```
 <controls:DataDisplayer Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="0"
    DataType="{x:Static res:Strings.PVUpper}"
    DataValue="{Binding PVUpper}"
    UnitText="{x:Static res:Strings.KgUnit}" />
```

I have this in my MainViewModel.cs

```
public double PVUpper { get; set; }
```

For those properties, which get data from the `res:Strings` works fine and display the correct values, but `DataValue` property always shows the default value of the DependencyProperty (9.9). The value of `PVUpper` changes in every second in the ViewModel so I would like to see this change on the View as well.

Comment: Do you get any Binding Errors in the output? You may want to check with some tool if the binding is correctly establishd and if the `DataContext` of your `DataDisplayer` is correct.

Comment: There is no Binding Error, the application runs fine but the value change does not visible on the screen. It is always `9.9`.

Comment: Ohh I think I see the error. You set the DataContext to `this` (in the constructor), but since the Binding for `DataValue` will be executed with the DataContex of `DataDisplayer ` there is no `PVUpper`-Property to bind onto.

Comment: So I should set the DataContext of the DataDisplayer in the MainView.xaml to MainView? If yes then how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is the wrong DataContex for the Binding. You set the `DataContext`-Property of your `DataDisplayer` to itself

> ```
> public DataDisplayer()
> {
>     InitializeComponent();
>     this.DataContext = this;
> }
> ```

So the Binding `DataValue="{Binding PVUpper}"` tries to find a property with the name `PVUpper` on your `DataDisplayer` instance, which of course dose not succeed.

So you should not do `this.DataContext = this;` and just leave the `DataContext` untouched (your control will inherit the datacontext of its parent).
You also will need to change the bindings in your `DataDisplayer.xaml` to address the changed DataContext.

But you can simplay add an `ElementName=dataDisplayer` to all the bindings to bind against your `DataDisplayer` instance.

So for example

```
<TextBlock FontWeight="ExtraLight" Text="{Binding UnitText}" />
```

becomes

```
<TextBlock FontWeight="ExtraLight" Text="{Binding UnitText, ElementName=dataDisplayer}" />
```

Comment: Thx, with this the binding is works fine, but the value on the screen is not changing when the value of `PVUpper` is changing.

Comment: You may need to add `Mode=OneWay` to the binding. I would recommend that you debug the property getter and setter to make sure that the values are actually changing (on both sides) and also to use a tool like Snoop to examin your UI